# How to return a promise from a Provider in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-suspense

I have a provider that does some work when it loads (one time). It adds a script tag for a map then when that script is loaded it initializes the map.

I want to the children to be able to use suspense. I'd like to return from that provider a promise which either throws if not resolved (for suspense) or it returns the map.

I can't figure out how to do this inside my component. Of note, I'm using nextJS so I have to make sure I'm on the client side too.

I made a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-leftpad-2zf2s?file=/src/index.js) to simplify it:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading</h1>}>
        <Child />
      </Suspense>
    </MyProvider>
  );
}
```

Child consumes the map and displays it, in this case it's just text:

```
const Child = () => {
  const { data } = useContext(context);

  const result = data.read();

  return <div>Result: {result}</div>;
};
```

Here is the provider:

```
const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // I do asynchronous work here which adds a script tag and when
    // it is fully loaded initializes a map. How do I pass this promise
    // down to children in a way that will work with suspense?
    const data = wrapPromise(
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("fetched data");
          resolve({
            name: "Ringo Starr"
          });
        }, 1000);
      })
    );
  }, []);
  return <context.Provider value={{ data }}>{children}</context.Provider>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create the promise once, and *memoize* it:

```
const data = useMemo(() => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, { name: "Ringo Starr" });
}), []);
```

Comment: Would this also only run once on mount on the client side? I'll give it a try tonight, thanks!